# SO Watch Face - Android Wear OS Watch Face and Complications

Tags: app, android

## Stack Overflow Wear OS Watch Face

[image: Stack Overflow Wear OS Watch Face]

[Demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVwtpdLeB2g)

Side by side comparison with the swag:

[image: Android Wear and the real swag]

This app was originally made for the [Time for some more swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319326/133343) competition on Meta.SE

### Main features

- Can display the UTC notch (when the StackExchange counters resets) regardless of your current timezone - even if it's not an integer one.
- Generic Wear OS complication that can show your (or anyone else's) reputation on a specific SE site.
- User ID is based on your site-wide account, so when switching between sites you'll always see your own reputation - unless you don't have an account on that site yet.
- Two watch faces that show the logo of the chosen SE site - a simpler one with a larger logo, and another more complex one that resembles the prize you could win in the [Time for some more swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319326/133343) competition

### Links:

- [Source code](https://github.com/sztupy/SOWatchFace) and Download
- [Google Play listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.sztupy.sowatchface)
- [Demo video of the watch in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVwtpdLeB2g) (shows version 5.0)

### Usage

Select the "SO Watch Face" in the watch face list to select it. Press the small cog to open up the settings.

*Options available*

- Complications: You can set the left and right complication
- Unread Notifications: You can set whether you would like to see the unread notification dot or not
- Display UTC Notch: You can enable/disable displaying when UTC midnight is on the watch face
- SWAG Watch Face: You can switch between the simpler display featuring a larger logo, or the more complex one that loogs like the SWAG you could win
- SE Site: Allows you to change which Stack Exchange site you wish to look at
- SE ID: Allows you to set which Stack Exchange Network User ID you wish the reputation complication to use. Pleae note: you have to set the site-wide network ID here, not the site specific ID.
- Site ID: This will show you the ID the reputation complications will use. This is a read-only field.

Also has two complications you can use in any watch face. They can be configured in the watch face configuration

### Potential improvements

- The list of Stack Exchange sites used is static and is from 12/12/2018. Any change after that in the list of available Stack Exchange sites is not reflected in the app. The list should be dynamic.
- The watch face and all complications use the same global setting for the selected site and selected user, meaning you can't have different settings for each of them. There should be separate settings for each complication and the watch face.
- Logos once downloaded are never updated - you need to clear the application's Data files to purge them. There should be a mechanism to clear them out occasionally.
- Color Scheme is aligned with Stack Overflow's site and not the other pages. The scheme should also dynamically update based on the chosen site.

### License

Licensed under the GPLv3 license.

### Updates:

#### v6.0 / v7.0

- From now on you have to set the Stack Exchange Network User ID, and not the site specific one.
- Given you have an account there when switching sites your Site specific user ID will always update based on your Network User ID, so you would always see your own reputation
- v7.0 includes some minor fixes to this feature as well

#### v5.0

[New Demonstration Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVwtpdLeB2g): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVwtpdLeB2g

[image: V5.0-1]
[image: V5.0-2]
[image: V5.0-3]
[image: V5.0-4]

*Major changes:*

- Removed all Stack Overflow icon from the build - should be much more compliant to the Trademark guidelines
- There is a box now to select which Stack Exchange site one wishes to use and the graphics will be applied based on that site
- All graphical detail (logos) are now downloaded and added to the watch faces dynamically based on the selected Stack Exchange site
- Added a new complication that just displays the selected site's logo.

*Minor fixes:*

- Complications now update automatically if the user id is changed
- Minute hand now moves appropriately
- Second hand now only moves in whole seconds

#### v4.0

Changes:

- Fixes problems with complications not updating
- Adds support to show next reputation milestone as range for complications
- Should now be available from the Play Store from the watch, just search for "Stack Overflow"

#### v3.0

[image: v3.0-1]
[image: v3.0-2]

- Settings page to set up the watch face
- Two different watch face - one that resembles the SWAG, the other one a more simpler one
- Supports two complications on the watch face
- Adds a new complication that shows a specific user's SO reputation

  - Works in other watch faces as well
  - Shows Jon Skeet's reputation by default
- Please note that the privacy policy was updated to contain that the SO user ID you set might be a PII, but it's only stored locally on the watch and only transmitted to the StackExchange API

#### v2.0

[image: v2.0]

- Nicer watch face resembling the swag much more
- Water resistant to 6 to 8 weeks

#### v1.0

[image: v1.0]

- Initial version
- Stack Overflow logo as a background
- Displays the UTC offset so you know when the Stack Overflow counters reset

Comment: This has to be the coolest idea ever for programmers who known Photoshop or graphic designers who can program! I want to design my own computerized watch face. Which watch did you buy?

Comment: It's a 2yr old Moto 360 2nd gen. The Wear OS documentation is not the best on how to create a watch face, but the demo app they have on github gives a good baseline.

Comment: I found the Australian link for this product. Motorola doesn't want to sell that device on their .com site for visitors in the USA. Here is the link for anyone else who is looking for this programmable smart watch: https://www.motorola.com.au/products/moto-360 The feature looks like it's called 'Live Dials'.

Comment: Motorola discontinued selling smartwatches around a year ago. You'll be better finding a company who still creates Wear OS devices, as there are still plenty of them with better support and everything: https://wearos.google.com/intl/en_uk/#find-your-watch